# PHP vs. Other Languages in Hadoop/MapReduce implementations, and in the Cloud generally

Tags: java, php, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm beginning to learn some Hadoop/MapReduce, coming mostly from a PHP background, with a little bit of Java and Python.

But, it seems like most implementations of MapReduce out there are in Java, Ruby, C++ or Python.

I've looked, and it looks like there are some Hadoop/MapReduce in PHP, but the overwhelming body of the literature seems to be dedicated to those 4 languages.

Is there a good reason why PHP is a 2nd class language in cloud computing projects like those that involve Hadoop/MapReduce? This is particularly surprising, considering that, outside of cloud computing world, PHP seems like its the most commonly supported language, to the detriment of the 3 above (sans C++) languages.

If this is arbitrary--if PHP is just as good at handling these operations as, say, Python, what libraries/projects should I look into?

Comment: Do you mean implementing Map/Reduce paradigm in PHP or for example writing jobs to be executed on Hadoop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP is designed primarily as a language for displaying output to a browser. Most jobs being run on MapReduce/Hadoop clusters have nothing to do with displaying output.

They instead tend to lean much more heavily towards data processing. PHP is *not* the most commonly supported language for data processing, by far. Thus, it's logical that the most common supported languages for data processing-related technologies don't include PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Doctrine MongoDB Object Document Mapper](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm). It supports [map/reduce](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm/1.0/docs/reference/map-reduce/en).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is PHP lack of support for multi-threading and process communication.

Comment: Not needed in Hadoop Streaming